# W/System.err(421): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: android

```
this code error:
04-02 03:01:52.552: I/params(421): [name=aad, category_id=0]
04-02 03:01:52.552: E/Log(421): Failed to download result..
04-02 03:01:52.552: W/System.err(421): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-02 03:01:52.552: W/System.err(421):  at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
04-02 03:01:52.562: W/System.err(421):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:93)
04-02 03:01:52.562: W/System.err(421):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
04-02 03:01:52.562: W/System.err(421):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
04-02 03:01:52.562: W/System.err(421):  at com.gift2u.products.ListProduct.onCreate(ListProduct.java:94
```

if i give params  [name=, category_id=0] all programming running right 
I write program search filter product_name or category_id.
thanks all for answer

Answer (score 1):

Your Json string is wrong format.

Replace [ ... ] by { ... }.

[ ] is a json array, not json object.